# Stand-alone React 18 page warning: importing createRoot from "react-dom"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a stand-alone webpage that uses React 18:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>Hello React!</title>
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
      <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="root"></div>

      <script type="text/babel">
      
      const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
      root.render(<h1>Hello React!</h1>);
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Although the page technically works, I see this error message in the console:

> Warning: You are importing createRoot from "react-dom" which is not
> supported. You should instead import it from "react-dom/client".

I'm not sure what to change in my script tags since I'm using the suggested [CDN links](https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html). I would have thought a file called **react-dom-client.development.js** would exist, but I don't see it:

https://unpkg.com/browse/react-dom@18.0.0/cjs/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore this warning. A fix is coming:
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24292#issuecomment-1091690844