# react@18 in "standalone" mode and get a warning using createRoot

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I'm using react@18 in "standalone" mode and get a warning using `createRoot`.

The reactjs code is inlined in the HTML file, in a script section -  . The HTML header in the current HTML file includes these sources:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
```

I attempt to access createRoot() like this:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
```

That line leads to this error -> Warning: You are importing createRoot from "react-dom" which is not supported. You should instead import it from "react-dom/client".

What is the correct way to import this from "react-dom/client"? What is the correct way to do this standalone - `<script src=" ... "></script>` to use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stand-alone React 18 page warning: importing createRoot from "react-dom"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71957303/stand-alone-react-18-page-warning-importing-createroot-from-react-dom)

Comment: This might Help 
https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/24274

This is main issue for react client dom error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the correct way to import this from "react-dom/client"?

You are using the correct way.

---

Unfortunately there's a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24221) inside the UMD build thats causing the error.

A fix has already [been merged](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/24274), but [UNPKG](https://unpkg.com/) does not yet serve the version which has the fix included.

---

For now: just ignore the warning.