# React 18 displays ReactDOM.render warning even though I switched to the new standard

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-18

I have switched to React 18 and followed official guide on how to change root's render method.

Here is my root's render code:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as any);
root.render(<App />);
```

Both `react` and `react-dom` are `^18.0.0`.

App is throwing this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By simply refactoring, the line of code below will also work

`import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";` 
`import App from "./components/App";` 
`createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App tab="home" />);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed type definitions for `react` and `react-dom` packages? You need to add `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` packages and set them in the `tsconfig.json` file. Keep in mind, package versions needs to be compatible. Also the expected parameter type of the `createRoot` method is `Element | DocumentFragment` so you can either use exclamation mark or [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like `as Element`.

**index.tsx**

```js
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(container!);
root.render(<App />);
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
"types": ["react", "react-dom"]
```

**package.json**

```json
"dependencies": {
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.4.2"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore it, https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24292#issuecomment-1091690844

A fix has already been merged, but UNPKG does not yet serve the version which has the fix included.
Author: 0stone0

Reference:
[react@18 in "standalone" mode and get a warning using createRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72000328/react18-in-standalone-mode-and-get-a-warning-using-createroot)