# Upgraded React 18.2.0 says I need to use createRoot even though I am using createRoot

Tags: reactjs

I am upgrading to react 18.2.0 but I'm getting the use createRoot error even though I am using createRoot. I see that others were having this issue around April `22. I've looked in the change logs and don't see any mention of it, but surely it has to have been fixed by now. Maybe not?

[React 18 displays ReactDOM.render warning even though I switched to the new standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075005/react-18-displays-reactdom-render-warning-even-though-i-switched-to-the-new-stan)

Package.json

```
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-color": "^2.19.3",
"react-cool-onclickoutside": "^1.6.2",
"react-csv": "^2.2.2",
"react-device-detect": "^1.17.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-heap": "^0.1.3",
"react-id-generator": "^3.0.1",
"react-map-gl": "^6.1.14",
"react-map-gl-draw": "0.21.1",
"react-mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^1.1.0",
"react-mentions": "^4.4.7",
"react-phone-input-2": "^2.14.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.3",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-script-hook": "^1.5.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"react-select": "^4.3.1",
"react-select-country-list": "^2.2.3",
```

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
...

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: Where are you seeing this? When running the app or during tests? You might have a dependency that hasn't switched.

Comment: This is when I'm running the app. Ugh! there's so many dependancies in this app

Comment: You could search the code of every package for the usage of `ReactDOM.render()`, but it's really not the end of the world. It's a warning you can safely ignore (for now).